# Break current loop iteration and continue loop in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

**data Retrieve from Database**

```
while($row_posts = mysql_fetch_array($run_posts))
    {
    $post_id1=$row_posts['userID'];
    $post_title=$row_posts['torrent_hash'];
```

**check hash value with transmission software**

```
try{
    $transmission = new Transmission\Transmission();
    $torrent = $transmission->get($post_title);
    $torrent->getName();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
          echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
       }
```

**If Hash id not found in transmission then show error like below**

```
Caught exception: Torrent with ID 58bd21a7938cb1d65f737bcb6031111816d924d9 not found 
Notice: Undefined variable: torrent in C:\xampp\htdocs\final\info.php on line 46

Fatal error: Call to a member function isFinished() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\final\info.php on line 46
```

I need Output Like If Runtime exception occurs then simply break the first loop and execute second value from database is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try command `continue;` in the catch block.

> continue is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

See [Php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)